# Subclassing and Exposing superclass - Is it a Facade design pattern?

Tags: inheritance, design-patterns, computer-science, facade

Lets assume we have a `class A`, and 2 subclasses of this class - `class A1` and `class A2`

If we do not know if an object coming in is of type A1 or A2, we do something like:
`object = incomingObject as A`

Is this still using the Facade design pattern? Or is there a different name for this pattern?(maybe just simple inheritance)

Comment: It probably depends a bit on your language and how it implements various concepts. I'm most familiar with C#. I wouldn't consider a design pattern to be a facade if it's not using an Interface rather than a base class. Subclasses would just be simple inheritance.

Comment: A façade bundles several interfaces into one. This is not the case here, IMO. What you described is called a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) — at least in apple's ecosystem.

Comment: @vikingosegundo you are right. maybe i am confusing between the two. Thanks!